# Black images when uploading in php

Tags: php, image, upload

Upload, at the front end, seems to work and although all the files are created successfully, they are all completely black. I'm sure it's something simple I am doing wrong but I've been staring at it for a while and I'm just not getting it.

I'm also untrained in php and I am trying to teach myself along the way.

I have been resizing the images proportionally and some of the widths and heights do have real numbers, does this make a difference? Should I round them to the nearest pixel?

Below is the section of code where the error is occurring. I think I know the line that is causing the issues, so I have marked it with "//error".

```
//Resize proportionally
for($i=0;$i<$image_count;$i++){
    $size = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"][$i]);
    $ratio = $size[0]/$size[1]; // width/height
    echo "<BR>Original width = ".$size[0]." Original height = ".$size[1]."<BR>";
    if( $ratio > 1) {
        $width = 500;
        $height = 500/$ratio;
    }
    else {
        $width = 500*$ratio;
        $height = 500;
    }
    echo "<BR>new width = ".$width." new height = ".$height."<BR>";
    // resample
    $image_p[$i] = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $image[$i] = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name".$i][$i]); //error
    imagecopyresampled($image_p[$i], $image[$i], 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $size[0], $size[1]);
    //echo "<BR>image".$i." has been resized and resampled";
}
```

I've also edited my php.ini file to include the following.

```
1.  ; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.  
2.  post_max_size = 700M  
3.    
4.  ; Maximum number of files. Added by DJ  
5.  max_file_uploads=500  
6.    
7.  ; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files. Added by DJ  
8.  upload_max_filesize = 50M
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Usually the image gets black if you pass incorrect x,y coordinates (out of the image). try debugging your x,y, height, width calculation.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. It looks as if the correct height and width are being generated from the original images. But I'll keep looking and will read up on your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Do not `echo` anything if you are attempting to actually output an image ( or many ), you need to use `imagejpeg()` and you need to set a header for content type ~ unless saving to disk

Comment: @RamRaider Further on in the code I use this code

if (imagejpeg($image_p[$i], $target_file[$i], 80)) { //output
          echo "<BR>The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$i]). " has been uploaded.<BR>";
       $uploadOK = 1;
      } 
      else {
          echo "<BR>Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.<BR>";
          $uploadOK = 0;
      }

Comment: if you echo anything and attempt to output the image to the browser you will get an error in the image and it'll display black

Comment: `["tmp_name".$i]` is incorrect

Comment: When I remove the $i from the temp name, I have other issues when it tries to look at the 2nd image in the array.

Comment: @RamRaider I do believe that this is the line that is causing me problems and that the rest of the code is working ok. I am sending an array of images rather than uploading the one and I didn't want to give them all the same temp_name, hence the addition of $i. Do you have any suggestions how I could fix this line?

Answer (score 0):

Initially I wasn't sure about the intended end for the script as the code posted was only a portion but if I have now understood correctly then the image processing has the end goal of saving a modified version of the uploaded file?

```
<?php
    define('KB',1024);
    define('MB',pow(KB,2));
    define('GB',pow(KB,3));
    define('TB',pow(KB,4));


    function uploaderror( $error ){ 
        switch( $error ) { 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: return "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini"; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE: return "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form"; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL: return "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded"; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE: return "No file was uploaded"; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR: return "Missing a temporary folder"; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE: return "Failed to write file to disk"; 
            case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION: return "File upload stopped by extension"; 
            default: return "Unknown upload error";
        }
    }
    function size( $i ) {
        if ( is_numeric( $i ) ) {
            if( $i > 0 && $i < KB ) {
                return "{$i} bytes";
            } elseif( $i >= KB && $i < MB ) {
                return round( ( $i / KB ),2 )."Kb";
            } elseif( $i >= MB && $i < GB ) {
                return round( ( $i / MB ),2 )."Mb";
            } elseif( $i >= GB && $i < TB ) {
                return round( ( $i / GB ),2 )."Gb";
            } elseif( $i >= TB ) {
                return round( ( $i / TB ),2 )."Tb";
            } else {
                #Computer will die
            }
        }
    }

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_FILES ) ){

        $errors=array();
        $feedback=array();

        /* maximum width or height */
        $maxdim=500;

        /* Obtain reference to files collection */
        $files=(object)$_FILES['fileToUpload'];

        /* location images will be saved to */
        $outputdir='c:/temp/fileuploads/2/';

        /* Process all files */
        if( count( $files->name ) > 1 ){

            /* Iterate through files collection */
            foreach( $files->name as $i => $void ){
                try{

                    $name = $files->name[$i];
                    $size = size( $files->size[$i] );
                    $type = $files->type[$i];
                    $tmp  = $files->tmp_name[$i];
                    $error= $files->error[$i];

                    /* save the file as */
                    $filename = $outputdir . $name;


                    if( !$error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK or !is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) ) throw new Exception( uploaderror( $error ) );
                    else {

                        list( $w, $h, $t, $a ) = getimagesize( $tmp );
                        $ratio = $w / $h;

                        if( $ratio==1 ){
                            $width=$height=$maxdim;
                        } else {
                            $width=ceil( $maxdim * $ratio );
                            $height=$maxdim;
                        }

                        $target=imagecreatetruecolor( $width, $height );
                        $source=imagecreatefromjpeg( $tmp );
                        $result=imagecopyresampled( $target, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $w, $h );

                        if( $result ){
                            /* save the modified image to disk */
                            $status=imagejpeg( $target, $filename );
                            $newsize = size( filesize( $filename ) );

                            /* free resources */
                            imagedestroy( $target );
                            imagedestroy( $source );

                            /* delete uploaded temp file */
                            @unlink( $tmp );

                            if( !$status )throw new Exception( 'Unable to save ' . $filename );
                            else $feedback[]="Success: '{$name}' saved as '{$filename}' was {$size} now {$newsize} - resized from dimensions [ W:{$w}, H:{$h} ] to [ W:{$width}, H:{$height} ] ";
                        }
                    }


                }catch( Exception $e ){
                    $errors[]=$e->getMessage();
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if( !empty( $errors ) ) echo '<pre>',print_r($errors,true),'</pre>';
            if( !empty( $feedback ) ) echo '<pre>',print_r($feedback,true),'</pre>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for this. I'll spend some time looking through it and update you.